# Laravel 4 remove Index.php from URL

Tags: php, laravel-4, pretty-urls

I need some help with laravel 4 application i need to remove Index.php from url i have tried the solution that has been mentioned in laravel documentation

```
Pretty URLs
Apache

The framework ships with a public/.htaccess file that is used to allow URLs without index.php. If you use Apache to serve your Laravel application, be sure to enable the mod_rewrite module.

If the .htaccess file that ships with Laravel does not work with your Apache installation, try this one:

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

any Suggestions :) ?

Comment: so if you go to yourwebsite.com/controller/action it's redirecting to yourwebsite.com/index.php/controller/action?

Comment: yes it does exactly like that

Answer (score 2):

**FOR LAMP SERVER**

Try the following steps,

1. Activate the mod_rewrite module with,

> sudo a2enmod rewrite

2. and restart the apache

> sudo service apache2 restart

3. To use mod_rewrite from within .htaccess files (which is a very common use case), edit the default VirtualHost with

> sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

4. Search for “DocumentRoot /var/www/html” and add the following lines directly below:

   ```
   <Directory "/var/www/html">` 
           AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ```
5. Save and exit the nano editor via `CTRL-X, “y”` and `ENTER`.
6. Restart the server again:

> sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">` 
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

uncomment `'LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so'` in apache `httpd.conf`
in 'public' folder check .htaccess file (created by default)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

just go to your apache settings folder, i use wamp so myne is

C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/httpd.conf - file

```
   // located on line 154 precisely... 

    #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so  

   // to 

    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

restart WAMP and BOOM!.. it works.

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite apache module may not be enabled by default. enable it and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

And it will works

Comment: In my case it is already enabled. But facing the same problem. Running above command says:    
`Module rewrite already enabled`

Answer (score 0):

I have read long posts and threads but nothing works then i found this and it works for me.

The easiest way to do this (and the way I always use) is to open up your Command prompt or Terminal and cd into the main directory of your project then run "`php artisan serve`". That's it. You're done. Don't believe me? Check out `http://localhost:8000` and admire your Laravel work.

http://michaelbrooks.co.uk/post/laravel-localhost-removing-public-index-php

Comment: Your answer is to use the built in *development* server? That's really bad advice.

Comment: here user have not mentioned that he is on the production server. I think so its best option to use when you are development mode.

Comment: Yes, your solution works properly. But what if I want to run in virtual host, i.e. I create a custom url?