# http://127.0.0.1/tp/index.php/movies change this url to http://127.0.0.1/tp/movies using .htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, libcmtd

I am using laravel framework for mtdb i wanna change http://127.0.0.1/tp/index.php/movies this url to
http://127.0.0.1/tp/movies  means i want to add to remove index.php using .htaccess

Here is the `.htaccess`

I have

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Post the .htaccess that you have

Comment: yes sir                                                                                                    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Can you please update the `.htaccess` in your question

Comment: sir it is in my root folder only

Comment: If you use laravel version 4, then the .htaccess should be inside your `public` folder right, why did you moved it to the root folder ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions for removing the `index.php` such as [Laravel 4 remove Index.php from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22365021/3282633)

But i would suggest you to rename the `server.php` in the your Laravel root folder to `index.php` and copy the `.htaccess` file from `/public` directory to your Laravel root folder.

Comment: yaa sir same error actually my file runs when i go through url http://127.0.0.1/tp/index.php/etcetc  and doesnt run when i go directly through http://127.0.0.1/tp/etcetc

Comment: May i know what error it throws `Page Not Found Exception` or a simple blank page ?

Comment: Actually i want to install mtdb movie database to my server and it get installed when i go through url http://127.0.0.1/tp/index.php/install   and  i want to install it using url http://127.0.0.1/tp/install/  means skipping index.php  in the url.. please help sir i m in an urgent need...thank you in advance

Comment: I don't know much about `mtdb`, may i know which laravel version you have currently ?