# Laravel Routing Issue: http://104.155.222.192/ works fine while http://104.155.222.192/home doesn't work in laravel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I have successfully installed laravel on Google VM instance Server address is '104.155.222.192'. When I open base URL Route works fine but when I access another URL like "104.155.222.192/home" it throws:

> [404 Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65QNw.png)

Please Help me to know, how to solve this.

Here is the code of my **route.php**

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    if(Auth::check()){
        return redirect('home');
    }
    return view('pages.index');
});

Route::controllers([
    'auth'      =>  'Auth\AuthController',
    'password'  =>  'Auth\PasswordController'
]);

Route::get('home', 'PageController@home')->middleware(['auth']);
Route::get('about','PageController@about');


Route::get('{userid}', 'ProfileController@index');
Route::get('{userid}/edit', 'ProfileController@editProfile')->middleware(['auth']);
```

Here is the **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

As far a I analysed it may be a error of htaccess because when I open "http://104.155.222.192/index.php/auth/register" it also works fine.

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and apache2 server

I have changed 000-default.conf from **html** to **public** directory

Comment: Did you try it without using the middleware?

Comment: Try this `RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]`

Comment: You are not removed index.php from your site. You can only run like this, http://104.155.222.192/index.php/home . To remove index.php ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365021/laravel-4-remove-index-php-from-url/27009666#27009666

Comment: Did you already enabled read write module in apache?

Comment: @TNC - "read write" module? You mean `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: Oh yes. `a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: @VinodVT Thanks your reference really works for me