# Why controller does not working using laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a test controller, i read its documentation and following the instruction during developer controller and view. But it does not working.

### Controller

project/app/http/controllers/TestController.php

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('test');
    }

}
?>
```

### Route

```
Route::get('test', 'TestController@index');
```

### View

```
project/resources/views/test.blade.php
```

simple html

I'm testing this controller using `http://localhost/project/public/test` but it does not work. Can any one guide me where i'm wrong.

Comment: what error show you?

Comment: @paranoid it showing this `The requested URL /project/public/test was not found on this server.`

Comment: tried this, http://localhost/project/public/index.php/test  ?

Comment: @VinodVT Thanks its working

Comment: @PhpDeveloper Check this to remove index.php from url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365021/laravel-4-remove-index-php-from-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your view    `<a src="{{ route('test') }}">test</a>`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11134711)

Comment: @jeff yes it does, it's a matter of him accessing the wrong url from his view. I showed how to echo the right url